# I can't connect to my Database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my error:

> MySQL ERROR: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

And this is my set.php

```
<?php
$sitename = "http://www.URL.COM";
$link = mysql_connect("(ip site)", "root", "password");
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[$rowname];
}
?>
```

I search all time answer but with no success.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. Have you created a user 'www-date'? Do they have a password?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: My guess is that it's logging in with local credentials - the code is most likely running under www-data and there is no corresponding account in the DB.

Comment: Someone can change this to work i need this ;/

Comment: @JayBlanchard no i dont have created user www-data

Comment: it's very unclear to me why it's not using `"root", "password"` credentials. But I can say that you need to actually call `fetchinfo`

Comment: Can you change this for me ? please

Comment: @jayblanchard I Use PHP5

Answer (score 3):

As you're not using password, why you write like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("(ip site)", "root", "password");
```

If your username = "root" on localhost then try to write the connection like the following way:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '{Your Password}');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('{Your DB Name}', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use {Your DB Name} : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

For details check: [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Note: Try to use PDO or mysqli

[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I cant use MySQLi and PDO i will stay on MySql

Comment: @FamousPL Tell Me your servername, DB username and password - once again.

Comment: i dont have domain but this is IP: http://91.134.209.193/ username is: root but password i cant tell you :D

Comment: @FamousPL, check i modified the code. If you run on localhost, then the above code should be Okey.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working but when i used mysql_* for DB connect, i used like the above. Please check for more information on [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php]

Comment: have you skype and can you see my problem?